# What are on chain smart contracts?

Tags: blockchain

My answer would be: On-chain smart contracts -- A set of rules as a transaction committed to the blockchain and then called by subsequent transactions. With on-chain smart contracts, the code that defines the set of rules becomes part of the ledger.

Doubts: I have an idea about committing transactions to the blockchain. But i need to know more about the calling a subsequent transactions. What does on chain smart contract do an how does it work in blockchain?

Please anyone explain me!

Answer (score 0):

Probably going against the site rules here but,

a smart contract is a set of attributes and methods, also called `promises` (the name has nothing to do with technology). smart contracts are a form of agreements that don't depend on on-paper terms and signatures but are enforced digitally (the only way until now, is cryptography).

On the blockchain the contract is embedded in the ledger via a transaction, which means it is part of the immutable data storage that the Distributed ledger(like ethereum) gives. So once deployed, the contract is unchangeable. So no tearing down the contract, no falsifying inputs. all of this is due to the way blockchain do take care of transactions and transaction parties and the way it ensures the integrity of the data it holds.

**The Ethereum Case :**

The smart contract on ethereum is an event driven program (like an operating system) that is always listening to external calls. these calls are the smart contract's method calls that can alter the contract's state variables. The contract's calls are stored as transactions on the blockchain and so can't be altered, so if a party has dealt with a certain contract it won't be able to deny it. This is also enforced by the fact that no one holds the contract, it is totally neutral and changeable only via signed transactions and also within the limits of the methods that the contract creates.

On Ethereum, contracts can handle currency. They have an account and it can have `Ether` in it. Other parties can(as defined by the contract) send or withdraw currency from the contract's account. This capability fo handling money via coded rules is the backbone of a fully trustable middle-man that will never turn biased to any involved party.